# Multiple classes in one .cpp file

Tags: c++

I was wondering if it is considered bad practice to have multiple classes in one .cpp file. I have a background in Objective-C, where this is rarely done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It makes for less readable code because you usually expect a class's definition to be in the header with the same name and the implementation in an implementation file with the same name.

There are cases in practice where a class is relatively small and closely-related small classes can be grouped together, but it's on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer points out, it makes for less readable code.

It is important to also consider the scope of a nested class:

> A nested class is declared within the scope of another class. The name
>   of a nested class is local to its enclosing class. Unless you use
>   explicit pointers, references, or object names, declarations in a
>   nested class can only use visible constructs, including type names,
>   static members, and enumerators from the enclosing class and global
>   variables.

[Source](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr061.htm)